# Lint splited OpenAPI definition

Tags: github, openapi

I've defined my services API using OpenAPI3 and am using GitHub for linting with Spectral by running the following script:

```
spectral lint ./api/**/*.{json,yml,yaml} --verbose
```

Later on, I've noticed that many of the objects are shared within my definitions and instead of duplicating them I've decided to create shared definition files that I could reference later on.

Everything is working great, besides the fact that at the moment the shared files are just regular YML files and not OpenAPI definitions. That means that there is no linting for those files. When I've tried to make those files an OpenAPI definition I had to add the `paths` definition (and others) which are not required in my shared files.

What is the best way to create a shared library in OpenAPI which could also be linted?

Something similar to what I've done you can find in the following [link](https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-8-splitting-specification-file/#basic-splitting)